Anyone know what font this is on the Fitzroy Tavern logo?
I am trying to identify the font used in the Fitzroy Tavern logo. Anyone have any ideas?
Fitzroy Tavern Logo

It's Trajan Bold, which is pretty distinctive with its narrow E and F, and the N which only has two serifs.  The font itself is based on the square capitals on the inscription at the base of Trajan's column in Rome.


